# iOS 5 + ARC - does assigning nil to pointer free up memory?

Tags: ios, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I'm trying to conform to Apple's guidelines about responding to low memory warnings in my app. The guidelines say: "Upon receiving (a low memory warning), your application must free up as much memory as possible by releasing objects that it does not need or clearing out memory caches that it can recreate later."

The question is, how to 'free up' memory, using ARC?

For example, suppose I have an image in the view hierarchy of a view that is not on screen. In didReceiveMemoryWarning, I currently remove it from the view by calling removeFromSuperview, but I still have a pointer to the UIImage itself. Should I also try to free up this memory? How? By assigning nil to the pointer?

TIA: John

Comment: Please provide more information abut the pointer.  Is it an ivar, local in a method, global, property?

Comment: Well the ones that I'm thinking about are UIImage * instance variables.

Comment: Okay, I think I solved my problem by 1) using a weak reference to the subview and 2) assigning nil to the pointer if the view was still around when didReceiveMemeoryWarning was executed (which it was every time I saw it in the debugger). Mainly, I think I just realized that you can't avoid memory warnings all the time... sometimes they are caused by other apps. You just need to handle them properly. After fixing up my memory warning handler, I only got the warning once, instead of every time I fired up UIImagePickerController. A big improvement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. By the time you get `-didReceiveMemoryWarning`, your view should have been released automatically by system and `-viewDidUnload` should be called. So if you don't hold references to subviews of the view you are not responsible to free them.
2. Otherwise, if you do hold references to some resources you want to free up, you just nullify your references by assigning "nil" to them for `NSObject`s, and call corresponding release functions for other types of references, e.g, `CFRelease` for `Core Foundation` objects.

Comment: H'mmm... the thing is, I do hold a reference to some subviews, because the app needs to be able to modify or remove the subviews, as part of the normal operation of the app. It's easy to be able to say [self.mySubView removeFromSuperview] when I need to, rather than traversing the subview tree each time I need to remove/modify a subview. But I guess that means the system can't release the subview, even if the view is release. Would the subview be properly released if I had a weak link to it?

Comment: Sure, you can use `__weak`, or you can simply set it to `nil` in `-viewDidUnload`.

Comment: In iOS6 viewDidUnload is no longer automatically called. You need to use didReceiveMemoryWarning.

Answer (score 0):

Make all `IBOutlet` properties with the `strong` attribute.

Set all `IBOutlet` properties all to `nil` in `viewDidUnload`.

Comment: @John specifically asked about ARC. Retain and release are no longer used.